# CodePipeline suddenly results in `Value at 'variables' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1`

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I have a CodePipeline (V1) in AWS for building my project.
While trying to find the right configuration for my buildspec file, I suddenly get the error below, when I press the "Build Release" button.
The error appears before the source step even seemed to have started. The error appears in red in the top of the screen, also indicating that this is not tied to a specific step.

```
aws codepipeline execution fails with 1 validation error detected: Value at 'variables' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1
```

I didn't change the pipeline settings between *working* and *error-is-shown*.

What I tried:

- I also reverted the changes in my buildspec file to when the pipeline was last working. But the error stays.
- Rechecked the pipeline configuration
- Rechecked the code build configuration
- Rechecked the buildspec file contents.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea about the reason, but I solved it by.

- edit pipline
- add variable, try to save, receive error, because V1 pipelines can't set variables
- remove the added variable via UI
- save
- save successful

I guess AWS simply got a hiccup here...

Comment: Got the sam ehiccup.  Did the trick!